# Function passed as props is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-props

I am trying to create a login module. I have a LoginView, which defines the view and a LoginController where I have defined all the user interactions. Now I am trying to incorporate a logic where in the LoginController will change the state of LoginView, as in change the value of isLoading from false to true in case all the input data is valid

LoginView

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import LoginController from '../Controller/LoginController.js';

import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      paddingTop: 23
   },
   input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },
   submitButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
      padding: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
   },
   submitButtonText:{
      color: 'white'
   }
});
export default class LoginView extends Component {

   constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
         isLoading: false
       }
   }

   changeLoadingState = (currentLoadingState) => {

      /* Create a loader screen and incorporate it here.
      */
      this.setState({isLoading: currentLoadingState} , () => {
         console.log("This is called when this.setState has resolved");
         console.log(this.state.isLoading);
       });
   }

  render() {

    const con = new LoginController(this.changeLoadingState);

     return (
        <Fragment>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
         <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Email"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {con.handleEmail}/>

            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Password"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {con.handlePassword}/>

            <TouchableOpacity
               style = {styles.submitButton}
               onPress = {
                    () => con.login()
               }>
               <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
         </SafeAreaView>
         </Fragment>
      );
        }
}
```

LoginController.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginNetworkManager from '../NetworkManager/LoginNetworkManager.js';
import Loader from '../../Utils/Loader.js';

export default class LoginController extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            email: null,
            password: null
         };
         this.changeLoadingState = this.changeLoadingState.bind(this);
      }

      changeLoadingState = (currentLoadingState) => {
         this.props.changeLoadingState(currentLoadingState);
      }

      handleEmail = (text) => {
         this.setState({email: text});
      }
      handlePassword = (text) => {
         this.setState({password: text});
      }

      login = () => {

         this.changeLoadingState(this.validate());
         if (this.validate() == true) {
            // Here in we will call the API
         } else {
            console.log(" It's false ");
            // Do nothing
         }
      }

      validate = () => {
         var reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
         var isValid = reg.test(this.email);


         if (isValid) {
            isValid = (this.password.trim().length > 0);
         }

         console.log(" Tis is Valid " + isValid);
         return isValid
      }
   }
```

The error when tapped the login button is

```js
   _this.props.changeLoadingState is not a function
    handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:86
    handleError @ setUpErrorHandling.js:23
    reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:42
    __guard @ MessageQueue.js:345
    callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:105
    (anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:80
```

Comment: That's not how props work. Your `LoginController` isn't a Component, or at least it's not used like one.

Comment: I used component because I wanted to send arguments as constructor injection. Basically the idea is LoginView will call LoginController to handle it's user interactions, any UI related changes will be done in the LoginView class. This way, the logic is seperated. However, if there is another logic that can be utilised to achieve the same ideal, please do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `LoginController` isn't a `Component`, if you want `LoginController` to be only a helper class, than you should remove `state` and `props` from it:

```
export default class LoginController {

      changeLoadingState = (currentLoadingState) => {

      }

      handleEmail = (text) => {

      }
      handlePassword = (text) => {

      }

      login = () => {

         this.changeLoadingState(this.validate());
         if (this.validate() == true) {
            // Here in we will call the API
         } else {
            console.log(" It's false ");
            // Do nothing
         }
      }

      validate = () => {
         var reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
         var isValid = reg.test(this.email);


         if (isValid) {
            isValid = (this.password.trim().length > 0);
         }

         console.log(" Tis is Valid " + isValid);
         return isValid
      }
   }
```

But if your goal is to abstract stateful logic, then you're doing it wrong. When you extend `React.Component` from a class you are explicitly telling React that this class is a `Component` therefore it should return `JSX` (render()) and should be initialized as a Component: `<LoginController />`, to abstract stateful logic you actually have a lot of really cool alternatives:

**High Order Components (HOC)**

This seens to be your use case, since you want a inject some props into `LoginView`, so you could abstract the logic to a HOC:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginNetworkManager from '../NetworkManager/LoginNetworkManager.js';
import Loader from '../../Utils/Loader.js';

export default withLogin = (ChildComponent) => {
    return class LoginController extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                email: null,
                password: null
            };
            this.changeLoadingState = this.changeLoadingState.bind(this);
        }
        /*
         Your logic
        */

        render(){
            return <ChildComponent {...this.state} />
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside `LoginView` you export like this: `export default withLogin(LoginView)` and `LoginController`'s state will be serialized inside `LoginView`'s props: `this.props.email` and `this.props.password`

And of course, everything that can be done with an HOC can also be done using `renderProps` and `hooks`.

Comment: In that case, the constructor gives an error. How can I pass the function as an argument then from LoginView to LoginController?

Comment: Gives an error cause you are trying to use state and props inside of a non component

Answer (score 0):

Your not passing the function as a prop to your LoginController component.

Comment: But I wrote const con = new LoginController(this.changeLoadingState);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dupocas's reply I understood when to utilise Components and when not to.

In my case, LoginController shouldn't be a component, because there is nothing to render in it's logic. It is purely a helper class.

The result code is now as follows

```
import React, { Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import LoginController from '../Controller/LoginController.js';
import Loader from '../../Utils/Loader';

import {
  View,
  StatusBar,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      paddingTop: 23
   },
   input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },
   submitButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
      padding: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
   },
   submitButtonText:{
      color: 'white'
   }
});
export default class LoginView extends Component {

   constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
         isLoading: false
       }
       con = new LoginController();
   }

   changeLoadingState = (currentLoadingState,completionBlock) => {
      this.setState({isLoading: currentLoadingState} , completionBlock);
   }

  render() {
     return (
        <Fragment>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
         <View style = {styles.container}>
         <Loader
          loading={this.state.isLoading} />
            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Email"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {con.handleEmail}/>

            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Password"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {con.handlePassword}/>

            <TouchableOpacity
               style = {styles.submitButton}
               onPress = {
                    () => con.login(this.changeLoadingState)
               }>
               <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
         </SafeAreaView>
         </Fragment>
      );
        }
}
```

LoginController is

```
import LoginNetworkManager from '../NetworkManager/LoginNetworkManager.js';
export default class LoginController  {

     email = null;
     password = null;

   changeLoadingState = (currentLoadingState,viewCallback,completionBlock) => {
      viewCallback(currentLoadingState,completionBlock);
      }

      handleEmail = (text) => {
         this.email = text
      }
      handlePassword = (text) => {
         this.password = text
      }

      login = (viewCallback) => {

         this.changeLoadingState(this.validate(),viewCallback);
         if (this.validate() == true) {

            let params = { email : this.email, password : this.password};

            LoginNetworkManager.loginAPI(params, (response,error) => {

               this.changeLoadingState(false,viewCallback,() => {

                  if (error){

                  }else{

                  }
                });
            });
         } 
      }

      validate = () => {
         var reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
         var isValid = reg.test(this.email);

         console.log(" this.email " + this.email);
         console.log(" this.password " + this.password);
         if (isValid) {
            isValid = (this.password.trim().length > 0);

            console.log(" password validation ----> " + isValid);
         }


         return isValid
      }
   }
```

Although, Dupocas's mentioned out about HOC and RenderProps and Hooks, I believe, that if I don't need a Component, I should try it in the non-component way, although it was insightful and might help me in future complex scenarios.